# Forall/3 by hand

Tags: prolog

I'd like to have a simple function, that takes all facts of one type and makes a list of it:

```
% Facts
fact('a','1').
fact('b','2').
fact('c','3').

% Call
all_facts(L) :- ......

% Expected
27 ?- all_facts(L).
L = [ ('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')].
```

I know that forall/3 does this fine already and is probably the preferred usage in any real-world scenario:

```
all_facts(L) :- findall(
                        (LETTER, NUMBER),
                        fact(LETTER, NUMBER),
                        L
                       ).
```

But I'm not trying to achieve this for the functionality here. I want is to understand the logic behind it, since I'm relatively new to Prolog. So far I'm here:

```
all_facts([(LETTER, NUMBER)|Rest]) :- fact(LETTER, NUMBER), fail.
```

This goes through all facts by order, as it keeps failing. My issue is to actually save them in a list.

Comment: See Richard O'Keefe's book **The Craft of Prolog** for a nice introduction to all-solutions predicates, common pitfalls, and how to implement them *correctly*.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I will check it out. For now though, can I have a hint on this specific issue?

Comment: Note that `listing(findall)` doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 2):

As @mat suggested from book The Craft of Prolog you could write:

```
all_facts( Template, Enumerator, List ) :-
        asserta( 'find all'( [] ) ),
        call( Enumerator ),
        asserta( 'find all'( {Template} ) ),
        fail
    ;
        'all found'( [], List ).

'all found'( SoFar, List ) :-
    retract( 'find all'( Item ) ),!,
    'all found'( Item, SoFar, List ). 

'all found'( [], List, List ).

'all found'( {Template}, SoFar, List ) :-
    'all found'( [Template|SoFar], List ).
```

Example:

```
?- all_facts((X,Y),fact(X,Y),L).
L = [ (a, '1'), (b, '2'), (c, '3')].
```

The basic idea behind this is to assert the terms loaded from your file statically (fact/2) but dynamically  (using assert) in order to be able to retract them when use them.